# What is the event I can handle dragged and external file onto my frame

Tags: python, events, drag-and-drop, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have code working to drop files onto a wx.FileDropTarget inside my frame. That is not my question.

I am trying to make a custom "hover" event that gets called 1 second after a outside dragged file is over my frame. Unfortunately wx.EVT_ENTER_WINDOW does not get called when an outside file is being dragged onto the frame from outside.

I want to avoid constant cursor checking and collision detection, as my app is more of a utility. (I will be having my app use little screen real estate and expand after "hovering" over a small frame for 1 second)

Ideally, I want to add code (my 1 sec timer) to the event that changes my cursor from the "file" to the "move" cursor when it hits my app.

I'm just learning wx, moving away from vb.NET. In vb.NET there was a Event Handler for "Control.DragEnter". That is what I am really looking for. The wxpython equivalent to vb.NET "Control.DragEnter"

```
Private Sub _DragEnter(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles Me.DragEnter
    If e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop) Then
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move
    End If
    tmrHover = New Timer
    AddHandler tmrHover.Tick, AddressOf tmrHover_Tick
    tmrHover.Interval = 1000
    tmrHover.Start()
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

-Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It wasn't clear when I first looked at the documentation, but here it is for everyone else:

```
class MyFileDropTarget(wx.FileDropTarget):

    def __init__(self, mainFrame):
            wx.FileDropTarget.__init__(self)
            self.window = mainFrame

    def OnDropFiles(self, x, y, filenames):
            for fil in filenames:
                    print str(fil)

    def OnEnter(self, x, y, nul):
            self.window.OnDragEnter()
            return wx.DragMove

    def OnLeave(self):
            self.window.OnDragLeave()
            return

    def OnDragOver(self, x, y, nul):
            return wx.DragMove
```

Thanks.

-Alex